# CPanel Cron stopped working after upgrade to Joomla 3.8.0

Tags: joomla, cron

I run a cron in Cpanel for Civicrm to send a newsletter once a month.  After the upgrade to Joomla 3.8.0 the cron has stopped working. This issue seems to be a big issue with this Joomla upgrade.  I tried to have my web host install a backup, but they only keep backups for 24 hours and they were unable to restore the previous Joomla version.   I have very little cron knowledge and need help figuring out how to get a cron working for this new version of Joomla so I can send out emails to my groups in Civicrm.

My current cron is the following:
wget 'http://www.divingrebels.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=login&pass=password&key=c121f216120e4362040e110a1f92db58' >/dev/null 2>&1

Thanks in advance
Danny

Comment: I just discovered the same issue. In times past, it’s been a user permissions error but I can’t seem to correct it. It is returning a 500 error but my logs aren’t showing the error

Answer (score 0):

The patch found here:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203
worked for me on CiviCRM 4.7.25 & J! 3.8.1